# How to use decodable protocol with custom type values in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, struct, decodable

I have 2 types of response depending on my reuest: First one:

```
{
    "status": "success"
    "data": {
        "user_id": 2,
        "user_name": "John"      
    }
}
```

And second one is:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "data": [],
}
```

I am using struct like that:

```
struct ValyutaListData:Decodable {
    let status: String? 
    let data: [String]?
}
```

But if response is first type response, then an error occured. Because In first Type response data is not array. It is Json object. Then i use structure like that:

```
struct ValyutaListData:Decodable {
    let status: String? 
    let data: Persondata?
}

struct Persondata: Decodable{
    let user_id: Int?
    let user_name: String?
}
```

If response is second type response, the error will be occured. What kind of of structure should use for dynamic type JSONs? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just have the `data`'s value always be an array of a single dictionary? Then the type is always an array, and if there is no data, it will simply be an empty array. If there is data, then you can just access the first element in `data`'s array, and it will be a dictionary?

Comment: @DavidChopin i dont write the services. Back end developer is another developer.

Comment: Is the value only an array when there is no data returned?

Comment: @DavidChopin yes, if there is no data empty array returned.

Comment: You will have to implement `init(from:)` yourself. Not difficult.

Comment: I would, if you can, check the value of  `"status"` before trying to encode anything. This way you can have `"data"` of type `[String:Any]` and only encode if `"status"` is equal to `"success"`

Comment: @DavidChopin i can tell the  backend developer to correct the json format. But i want to find solution for this problem :)

Comment: @matt i searched init(from:) but i can not find solution for this type json

Comment: Actually now that I think of it I have a better idea. :) Just have two ValyutaListData types - let's call them ValyutaListData1 and ValyutaListData2. Now `try` to decode using one of them and if you fail (in good order) then `try` with the other one.

Comment: @matt i used this solution. but i think if we have 3 or more types of response, should i have create 3 or more structure? I think it is not good idea )

Comment: :) That's a good objection. I was just trying to keep it very simple. Then writing `init(from:)` is a better approach.

Comment: @NicatGüliyev "Back end developer is another developer." I would recommend you speak with them and have them fix it. Their job is literally to serve you good data. Part of that is modelling it in a way that you can consume it easily/naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reasonable solution is an enum with associated type(s)

```
struct User : Decodable {
    let userId: Int
    let userName: String
}

enum Result : Decodable {
    case success(User), failure

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case status, data }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let status = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .status)
        if status == "success" {
            let userData = try container.decode(User.self, forKey: .data)
            self = .success(userData)
        } else {
            self = .failure
        }
    }
}
```

And use it

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data)
    switch result {
      case .success(let user): print(user)
      case .failure: print("An error occurred")
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: thank you for this post. i am trying understand and use it :)

Comment: I do not understand anything. it is difficult

Comment: `status` can be "success" or "error", in case of success the user is decoded and attached to the `success` case otherwise the `failure` case is returned.

Comment: @NicatGüliyev I recommend you read the [Swift Language Guide.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) It has an entire section on enums that I would recommend you check out. Seriously, it's a great book. If I were running a team, I wouldn't let anyone touch prod code before going through it cover to cover. Otherwise we're trying to compose a song without knowing what notes are available to us.