# Decoding JSON Response with same envelope but different content

Tags: json, swift, decoder, decodable

I am accessing a web api and as response it sends different payloads wrapped in same envelope like that:

Get a list of recipes:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "messages": [],
    "input": null,
    "output": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Egg with bacon"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Ice cream"
        }
    ]
}
```

Get a single recipe:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "messages": [],
    "input": {"id": 1},
    "output": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Egg with bacon"
    }
}
```

An error response:

```
{
    "status": "ERROR",
    "messages": ["Recipe not found"],
    "input": {"id": 4},
    "output": null
}
```

List of categories:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "messages": [],
    "input": null,
    "output": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Deserts"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Main Courses"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, envelope keys are always present. Input is a key-value object or null, messages is always an array of strings or empty array, status is string. But output can be different. It can be a type of Recipe struct, array of Recipe structs or a Category struct.

My question is: How can i decode this json without writing every time the same decoding logic for envelope? I want to write a decoder just once for envelope and inject different decoders for output.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192100/how-to-use-decodable-protocol-with-custom-type-values-in-swift/58192267#58192267

Comment: @vadian Your solution imply that the `output` type can be determined with the `status` property, which seems not to be the case here.

Comment: @rraphael not by the status property but with the input property, if it is null then output is an array otherwise it is a single element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a decodable struct that you will use to wrap your input and output into.

This will look like:

```swift
struct ResponseContainer<Input: Decodable, Output: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var status: String
    var messages: [String]
    var input: Input?
    var output: Output
}
```

Using this, if you want to decode a single Recipe, you just wrap your `Recipe` struct using into the response container:

```swift
// used to decode the `input`
struct InputId: Decodable {
    var id: Int
}

// content of the `output`
struct Recipe: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
}

try? JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseContainer<InputId, Recipe>.self, from: singleRecipeJson)
```

If you want to decode a list of recipes, just go the same way with another struct or an array:

```swift
// As the input is expected to be null, you can use a dummy struct in the wrapper.
struct Empty: Decodable {}

try! JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseContainer<Empty, [Recipe]>.self, from: multipleRecipeJson)
```

**Note:** The dummy struct `Empty` might not be useful as it add a lot of complexity, and is used to parse the `input` property of the payload, which look like something you sent to the API (so basically you already know it, and it can be ignored). In that case, the wrapper would look like that:

```swift
struct ResponseContainer<Output: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var status: String
    var messages: [String]
    var output: Output
}
```

Comment: On Swift Playground i implemented your solution in isolation but i get this message: `Expression implicitly coerced from 'Recipe?' to 'Any'`

Comment: On which line? I implemented it myself before posting the response.

Comment: i wrote it like that: https://gist.github.com/cnkt/9fb98c4719850b64deed6c2ae5b88a48

Comment: `let recipe: Recipe = container?.output`, `recipe` is an optional, you should write it like that `let recipe: Recipe? = // ...`, or just remove the type and let swift do its magic `let recipe = container?.output`

Comment: i tried both `let recipe: Recipe? = container?.output`and `let recipe = container?.output` and it still says `Expression implicitly coerced from 'Recipe?' to 'Any'`

Comment: Oh, this is just because you use `print()` with an `Optional`, nothing to do with the decoding. To remove this warning, you must remove the optional by providing a default value, force unwrapping, or explicitly cast it to `Any`.

Comment: Thanks. I think i can figure out the rest.